# Grub boot-loader doesn't start up

Tags: boot, grub2, acer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I installed Ubuntu through usb on my netbook today (An aspire one D257 netbook). The thing is, this netbook boots into a Chrome OS kinda thing then to Windows. After I installed Ubuntu and restarted, the GRUB boot loader doesn't even show up. It boots to Chrome OS then Windows. I haven't got the slightest idea what to do.

Netbook info:

- Processor: Intel Atom N570 (1.66GHz, 1MB L2 Cache)
- Memory: 2GB DDR3
- Memory Storage: 320 GB HDD

Comment: This problem is caused by Ubuntu's installer not installing the GRUB2 boot loader to the master boot record (or not doing so properly). It can be fixed with [the instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) even though the problem here is not caused by a recent Windows installation (**and this question will probably be closed as a duplicate of that**). If you prefer, [the methods here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System) are good too.

Comment: Dayummm you guys work fast, wasn't expecting an answer so soon! Ill try this and report back